# How to avoid comma at the end when creating a tuple?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have the following query in my python code:

```
query = """SELECT id
           FROM dings_archive
           WHERE doorbot_id IN {doorbot_ids};
        """

query = query.format(doorbot_ids=tuple(doorbot_ids))
```

`doorbot_ids` has type `List[int]` and I have a problem when my array contains just 1 element, because after `query.format` I have the following query:

```
SELECT id
FROM dings_archive
WHERE doorbot_id IN (123,);
```

As you see I have a bug because of comma `,` at the end. How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should do `query.format(doorbot_ids=", ".join(doorbot_ids))` (add the parenthesis manually in `query`)

Comment: its because door_bots is a tuple

Comment: @RompePC that's a bad idea, as people could potentially inject SQL code and wreak havok.

Comment: take repr from the list  or tuple and do some regex?

Comment: @Nils Werner The final SQL would be the same in both cases (except for the final comma), `(123)`, I don't see why it could wreak havok. If it fails in one, it fails in the other. Another case is that he/she is escaping values when doing it.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent SQL injection you should never use automatic casting of tuple to strings (what you are currently doing), or manually join a list of values before passing it to the driver.

You are currently making use of the fact that a tuple cast to string yields reasonable results:

```
str((1, 2))
# '(1, 2)'
```

but as you have noticed, single element tuples yield syntax errors:

```
str((1, ))
# '(1,)'
```

Some have suggested to concatenate the list manually:

```
','.join((1, 2))
# '1,2'
```

which would also work for single element tuples:

```
','.join((1,))
# '1'
```

however this opens the door to SQL injections, as the comma is in fact a control statement for MySQL, not just a value. So if somebody was able to sneak control statements in your list, they could inject code:

```
','.join((1,'1) OR 1=1 --'))
# '1,1) OR 1=1 --'
```

To be safe against such attacks you should prepare a query with exactly as many placeholders as elements in your list of id's:

```
doorbot_ids = [1, 2]

query = "SELECT id FROM dings_archive WHERE doorbot_id IN ({});".format(','.join(['%s'] * len(doorbot_ids)))
```

This returns a new query with exactly as many placeholders as required:

```
'SELECT id FROM dings_archive WHERE doorbot_id IN (%s,%s);'
```

and each placeholder is then filled with a value:

```
query = cursor.execute(query, doorbot_ids)
```

Comment: what about this `query = query.format(doorbot_ids ='(%s)' % ', '.join(map(repr, doorbot_ids)))` ? Is it any difference between time complexity with your algo?

Comment: also this `query = query.format(doorbot_ids)` didn't filled placeholder with a value. After the execution I got `SELECT id FROM dings_archive WHERE doorbot_id IN (%s);`

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistyped. You should obviously use `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: The first question is answered in my answer. Don't do this.

Comment: This will fail for one element list as it will put a comma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thinking outside the box here: If you have to use a tuple in a `WHERE IN` clause you could always test for the length of the tuple. if the tuple length == 1, convert it into a list using `list(tuple_object)`, append the list with the value at index 0 then convert it back to tuple!
Steps:
`1. the_single_value_tuple=('Salim',)`
`2. a_list= list(the_single_value_tuple)`
`3. return tuple(a_list.append(a_list[0])`

Answer (score -1):

Do not convert list to tuple, use it directly:

```
query = """SELECT id
           FROM dings_archive
           WHERE doorbot_id = any(%s);
        """
...
cursor.mogrify(query, (doorbot_ids,))
```